# Centroid and area of polygon using F#

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary, f#

I've written a function to find out the area and centroid of a polygon (based on this ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid )

However, I am very new to F# and I don't know how to convert this function from VB.NET to F# (VS2010). If anyone could please help me, that would be really appreciated (Assuming that in F# I already have a type called Point2D, and the input of F# function is a list of point2D) . My first attempt is below the VB code. But I don't like my version, since it has to calculate Cx, Cy ,and A serparately - which is not a true reflection of my VB code counterpart

```
 Private Function Find_Centroid_And_Area(ByVal List As List(Of Point2D)) As AreaCentroid
     Dim result As New AreaCentroid()
     Try

        Dim Qx As Double = 0
        Dim Qy As Double = 0

        Dim A As Double = 0
        Dim Cx As Single = 0
        Dim Cy As Single = 0
        Dim P1 As Point2D = Nothing
        Dim P2 As Point2D = Nothing
        For i As Integer = 0 To List.Count - 1
           P1 = List(i)
           Select Case i
              Case List.Count - 1
                 P2 = List(0)
              Case Else
                 P2 = List(i + 1)
           End Select



           Dim Dx As Double = P2.X - P1.X
           Dim Dy As Double = P2.Y - P1.Y
           Dim Lx As Double = P1.X + (Dx / 3)
           Dim Ly As Double = P1.Y + (Dy / 3)

           A += (Dx * (P1.Y + P2.Y)) / 2
           Qx += (Dx * ((P1.Y ^ 2) + (Dy * Ly))) / 2
           Qy -= (Dy * ((P1.X ^ 2) + (Dx * Lx))) / 2


        Next

        Cx = CSng(Qy / A)
        Cy = CSng(Qx / A)

        Dim Centroid As New Point2D(Cx, Cy)
        Dim Area As Double = System.Math.Abs(A)


        result.Area = Area
        result.Centroid = Centroid


     Catch ex As Exception

     End Try

     Return result
  End Function
```

and here is my attempt :

```ml
type Point2D =  
 struct 
    val X:float
    val Y:float
    new(x:float, y:float) = {X=x; Y=y}
 end

let PolygonCentroidArea (points: Point2D list) =    
   let length = List.length points
   match length < 3 with
   | true -> 
        let A = 0.0
        let Cx = (points |> List.map (fun p -> p.X) |> List.average)
        let Cy = (points |> List.map (fun p -> p.Y) |> List.average)
        (A, Point2D(Cx,Cy)) // returned value
   | false ->
      let TakeFirst2ItemInList (pointList : Point2D list) =
            let p1 = List.head pointList
            let tail = List.tail pointList
            let p2 = List.head tail
            let newList = List.tail tail
            (p1,p2,newList)

      let rec Area pointList = 
              match (List.length pointList) with
              | 0 -> 0.0
              | _ ->
                    let (p1,p2,newList) = TakeFirst2ItemInList pointList
                    (p1.X+p2.Y-p2.X*p1.Y) + Area newList

      let rec Cx pointList = 
             match (List.length pointList) with
             | 0 -> 0.0
             | _ ->
                    let (p1,p2,newList) = TakeFirst2ItemInList pointList
                    (p1.X+p2.X)*(p1.X*p2.Y-p2.X*p1.Y) + Cx newList

      let rec Cy pointList = 
             match (List.length pointList) with
             | 0 -> 0.0
             | _ ->
                    let (p1,p2,newList) = TakeFirst2ItemInList pointList
                    (p1.Y+p2.Y)*(p1.Y*p2.X-p2.Y*p1.X) + Cy newList

      let FinalArea = 1.0/2.0 * abs(Area points)
      let FinalCx = 1.0/(6.0*FinalArea) * Cx points
      let FinalCy = 1.0/(6.0*FinalArea) * Cy points

      (FinalArea, Point2D(FinalCx,FinalCy))
```

Comment: Post your attempt; SO is not a code translation service. ;-]

Comment: I've added my attempt - thanks for the reminder

Comment: it does. Somehow when i copied it here, the indent becomes incorrect which I've just fixed.

Comment: OK, now it compiles but if I input a rectangle of 0,0 1,0 1,1 0,1 I get a centroid of 0.166, -0.333 does it makes sense?

Comment: there might be an error in the calculation here and there. However, it is not my point. The point here is, my F# code is way too lengthy it is even longer than the VB.NET code. F# means to be very short. I don't know how to write the code to use the List.reduce or List.Fold to achieve my goal. There must be a way, and it should be very short.

Comment: Use pairwise before folding. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did translations from VB in the past, my advice is have a first working version with the same structure as the original VB Code:

```ml
type Point2D =
    struct 
        val X:float
        val Y:float
        new(x:float, y:float) = {X =x; Y=y}
    end

let rec PolygonCentroidArea (points: Point2D list) =
    let mutable Qx = 0.
    let mutable Qy = 0.
    let mutable A  = 0.

    let length = List.length points

    for i = 0 to length-1 do 
        let P1 = points.[i]
        let P2 = 
            if i = length - 1 then points.[0] 
            else points.[i + 1]

        let Dx = P2.X - P1.X
        let Dy = P2.Y - P1.Y
        let Lx = P1.X + (Dx / 3.)
        let Ly = P1.Y + (Dy / 3.)

        A <- A + (Dx * (P1.Y + P2.Y)) / 2.
        Qx <- Qx +  (Dx * (pown P1.Y 2 + Dy * Ly))  / 2.
        Qy <- Qy - ((Dy * (pown P1.X 2 + Dx * Lx))) / 2.

    let Cx = Qy / A
    let Cy = Qx / A

    (abs A, Point2D(Cx, Cy))
```

Once here we can refactor the function to a more F#-ish solution. The mutables and the loops may be converted to folds. In this case we use two consecutive elements from the list, so it sounds that we may use Seq.pairwise somewhere, also we can rearrange the calculation as you did in your answer.
Here's my solution:

```ml
let PolygonCentroidArea (points: Point2D list) =       
    let f (a, qx, qy) (p1: Point2D,p2: Point2D) = 
        let area  = a  + p1.X * p2.Y - p1.Y * p2.X
        let centX = qx + (p1.X + p2.X) * (p1.X + p2.Y - p1.Y * p2.X)
        let centY = qy + (p1.Y + p2.Y) * (p1.X + p2.Y - p1.Y * p2.X)
        area, centX, centY
    let a, qx, qy = Seq.fold f (0., 0., 0.) (Seq.pairwise (points @ [points.Head]))
    abs a / 2., Point2D(qx / 6. / abs a, qy / 6. / abs a)
```

Comment: This happens to return the right results for the unit square. You may want to factor out the common element in the calculations, magnitude of the vector's cross product.

Comment: Sure, if you want to optimise the code there are many things to factor out. But I think the question was focusing about reducing the amount of code.

Comment: Your solution is great. and it is way better than mine. Also, yes, it is as short as I expected. Just a bit of curiosity, though it is not directly related to the original question: How would you suggest me to do if the calculations involve more than every 2 items ? Seq.pairwise, as the name suggests, works only with every 2 items.

Comment: Thanks. Use Seq.windowed for n items.

Comment: Awesome - that's the thing I've been looking for ages. Sometimes we just need the right keyword. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on people's answers and ideas, and for the balance between readability and the conciseness of the code - here I am editing my original solution - which may potentially help others looking for the solutions of the same issue:

```ml
type Point2D =
struct 
    val X:float
    val Y:float
    new(x,y) = {X=x;Y=y}
end

let PolygonCentroidArea (points: Point2D list) = 
    let Elemement ((p1:Point2D), (p2:Point2D)) = 
        let cross = p1.X * p2.Y - p1.Y * p2.X
        let A  = cross
        let Cx = cross * (p1.X+p2.X)
        let Cy = cross * (p1.Y+p2.Y)
        (A, Cx,Cy)

    let SumElement (a1,cx1,cy1) (a2,cx2,cy2) = (a1+a2,cx1+cx2,cy1+cy2)

    let (A ,Cx, Cy) = 
         points
         |> Seq.pairwise
         |> Seq.map Elemement
         |> Seq.fold SumElement  (0.,0.,0.)

    (abs A/2. ,Cx/(6.*abs A), Cy/(6.*abs A))

let points = [Point2D(1.,0.); Point2D(5.,0.); Point2D(5.,2.); Point2D(1.,2.); Point2D(1.,0.)]
let test = PolygonCentroidArea points
//val test : float * float * float = (8.0, 1.5, 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the gist of the other answers is perfectly acceptable, I'm slightly worried by the erroneous result. Let me suggest to introduce a helper type which can perform the summation, allowing us to replace the unintuitive `fold` by the more natural `sum`.

```ml
type Sum3 = internal Sum3 of float * float * float with
    static member Zero = Sum3(0., 0., 0.)
    static member (+) (Sum3(a, b, c), Sum3(x, y, z)) = Sum3(a + x, b + y, c + z)

let polygonCentroidArea points =
    let (Sum3(a, cx, cy)) =
        points @ [List.head points] 
        |> Seq.pairwise
        |> Seq.sumBy (fun ((x0, y0), (x1, y1)) ->
            let z = x0 * y1 - x1 * y0 in Sum3(z, (x0 + x1) * z, (y0 + y1) * z) )
    let a = abs a / 2. in a, cx / 6. / a, cy / 6. / a

polygonCentroidArea[0., 0.; 4., 0.; 4., 2.; 0., 2.]
// val it : float * float * float = (8.0, 2.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: very interesting approach!